# how to get method by reflection's getmethod techenology and method is overrided and paramters has reference self-defined paramter

Tags: c#, reflection, getmethod

### case as followed:

in the project a

```
public class X1
{
  public string Name="X1";
}

public class X2
{
  public string GetName(string name)
  {
   return "";
  }

  public string GetName(string name,ref X1 x1)
  {
   return "";
  }
}
```

question:

how to get 'GetName' MethodInfo by reflection's getmethd function in other project

Comment: Nitpick about the terminology in the title - that method is *overloaded*, not *overridden*.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- You can call `typeof(X2).GetMethods()` and then just filter out the ones with the wrong names. This can sometimes be easier than calling `GetMethod()` providing the exact data.
- You can use `Type.MakeByRefType` to specify the `ref` parameter type in a call to `Type.GetMethod()`. So in this case you'd use (assuming you want the second of the methods shown):

  ```
  MethodInfo method = typeof(X2).GetMethod
      ("GetName", new [] { typeof(string), typeof(X1).MakeByRefType() });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var method1 = typeof(X2).GetMethod("GetName", new[] { typeof(string) });
var method2 = typeof(X2).GetMethod("GetName", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(X1).MakeByRefType() });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
foreach (var mi in typeof(X2).GetMethods())
{
    if (mi.Name.Equals("GetName"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method Name : {0}", mi.Name);
        var miPerms = mi.GetParameters();
        if (miPerms.Count() > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Params : {0}", miPerms.Select(p => p.ParameterType + " " + p.Name).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b));
    }
}
```